# Disable a link in IE9 - prototype stop() not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, prototypejs, dom-events

IE9 is still in Beta, but all the same, here is a question:

Using prototype.js 1.6.1, proper form for adding a click event to a link, and override the default link behavior, would be:

```
mylink.observe('click', function(e){
   doSomething();
   e.stop();
});
```

While this works perfectly in every other browser that I tried, IE9 is a unique case. The default event behavior fires and my link takes me to the linked location. It seems that `stop()` isn't doing its job in IE9.

The following code works perfectly in IE9:

```
mylink.onclick = function(){
   doSomething();
   return false;
}
```

Any idea what I could do to fix the prototype methodology for use in IE9?

Comment: Why are you devving in IE9 **beta** for, again?

Comment: Just trying to future proof my site. I think prototype 1.7 will alleviate the issue, since they have been working to accommodate IE9 (http://www.prototypejs.org/2010/10/12/prototype-1-7-rc3-support-for-ie9)

Answer (score 9):

prototype.js versions less than 1.7 does browser-sniffing to apply cross-browser compatible fixes.

prototype.js overwrites the native methods with it's implementation, which fails in IE 9; even-though it has support for DOM Level 2 Events.

The newer version of prototype.js doesn't have this issue as it does 'feature detection' rather than 'browser-sniffing'

Comment: Specifically, older versions of prototype override preventDefault() in such a way that the default is no longer prevented.

Comment: The Event.stop() method didn't work in 1.7rc2 on IE9. In the final release of 1.7, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Change document mode to IE8 standards by putting the following tag inside `<head></head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```